# Is there an implementation of convolutional lstm in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am currently studying tensorflow. I just made some simple codes like CNN, RNN ans LSTM and so on. And now I want to implement convolutional lstm. I read [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04214) and tried to implement it as an exercise. However, there were, as far as I searched, no codes available in the internet. If someone knows where the available source code is, please let me know.

Comment: maybe this https://github.com/loliverhennigh/Convolutional-LSTM-in-Tensorflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is done in the Neural GPU TensorFlow model by Łukasz Kaiser and Ilya Sutskever.

It uses GRUs rather than LSTMs, but those are very similar cell types. The model is also a little different from the typical RNN implementations. The nuance is that the model does not accept new inputs in time past the first time step: the inputs are fed to the initial cell state so that this "mental image" state evolves trough timesteps.

The paper is [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08228). 
The neural GPU model implementation in TensorFlow can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/neural_gpu).